# Error al añadir un implementation

Tags: android

estoy intentando añadir este implementation:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
```

Pero al sincronizar el proyecto me da este error:

```
ERROR: Could not get unknown property 'lifecycle_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

El implementation lo he sacado de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234180/issue-violation-of-interfering-with-apps-third-party-ads-or-device-functional

Mi build.grade:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'

    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

Comment: tienes que definir lifecycle_version dentro de las dependencias ->`def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"`, o colocar directamente la version ->`implementation  'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.0.0'`

Comment: Justo era eso, gracias. Por si alguien le sirve de ayuda en futuro, solo deja definirlo como max con la versión 1.1.1

Comment: lo colocare como respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que definir lifecycle_version dentro de las dependencias

`def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"`

o colocar directamente la version

`implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:2.0.0'`